# JS creating multi value objects array from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, reduce

Trying to get this `['Team Instinct', 'Team Valor', 'Team Mystic']`

To this

```
[{
    answer: "Team Instinct",
    id: asdfsodijha120-938a //nanoid()
 },
 {
    answer: "Team Valor",
    id: 12390i1-293-12093a2 //nanoid()
 },
 {
    answer: "Team Mystic",
    id: 123908320i09i09ss8a //nanoid()
 }
]
```

What i tried so far

```
const { nanoid } = require("nanoid")

const array = ['Team Instinct', 'Team Valor', 'Team Mystic']
let object = {}

obcject = array.reduce((prevValue,currentValue) => {
    prevValue.push({
        answer: currentValue,
        id: nanoid()
    })
},[])
```

**ERROR I GET `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return prevValue;

```
 const { nanoid } = require("nanoid")
    
    const array = ['Team Instinct', 'Team Valor', 'Team Mystic']
    let object = {}
    
    obcject = array.reduce((prevValue,currentValue) => {
        prevValue.push({
            answer: currentValue,
            id: nanoid()
        })
        return prevValue
    
    },[])
```

Comment: Works ! thanks Andrii

Answer (score 3):

Orig answer is correct, you're missing the return. However, here's an alternate way of writing it

```js
const { nanoid } = require("nanoid")
let object = ['Team Instinct', 'Team Valor', 'Team Mystic'].reduce((prevValue, currentValue) => ([...prevValue, {
  answer: currentValue,
  id: nanoid()
}]), [])
```

Comment: cool twist.thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you use a reducer
You lust return the value after pushing in it.

So first error, you never return the result in the callback function.
The seconde one, is that you trying then to assign the result of the reduce (an array) to an object.

```
const { nanoid } = require("nanoid");

const array = ['Team Instinct', 'Team Valor', 'Team Mystic'];

const result = array.reduce((prevValue,currentValue) => {
    prevValue.push({
        answer: currentValue,
        id: nanoid()
    });
    return prevValue;
},[]);
```